# Resizing a External HD without losing data?

Tags: partitioning, backup, external-hdd

So, I'm trying to create a FAT32 partition on my NTSF 2TB External HDD.
The thing is, I have more than 600 gb of data and I have, right now, only about 50 gb free on my PC, so I cant back up.

Is there a way to create a new partition on my external drive without losing the 600GB+ of data?

Comment: Are you familiar with gparted?

Comment: If the goal is to modify your NTFS partition, I would *strongly* recommend doing it in Windows.

Comment: It can be done in many ways; but it's a risky procedure, so backups are considered *essential*.  You can do it without them for sure, you're just accepting that risk.